# What does compilation flag -static really means for gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc

For example I did this:

```
${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -static myinit.c -o myinit
```

Also I did this without static:

```
${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc  myinit.c -o myinit
```

There is no effect in my case, in both cases binary gives same result.

So what is the role of static here?

Here is the program I am compiling:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Hello world from %s!\n", __FILE__);
    while (1) { }
    return 0;
}
```

Also

`${CROSS_COMPILE}` is  `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-`

Comment: You did tag with C++ too. Did you test with g++ and a small c++ program too or is this unrelated to c++?

Comment: @stefan Sorry I did not test it with g++. Kindly edit if you think this is only C specific.

Comment: @user12799508 I've asked because there are huge differences in the languages. That doesn't mean that the compiler flag behaves differently, but you should always flag just with the language you're interested in.

Comment: @stefan OK!! in future I will take care of this. thanks

Comment: @user2799508 Why do you not remove that irrelevant tag in this time?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ldd myinit
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5dbfe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7ec63ce000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7ec67c0000)
$ ldd myinit_static 
    not a dynamic executable


$ ll
total 884
drwxrwxr-x  2 jarod jarod   4096 Jun  7 16:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 38 jarod jarod   4096 Jun  7 15:59 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 jarod jarod   8567 Jun  7 16:00 myinit*
-rw-rw-r--  1 jarod jarod    136 Jun  7 16:00 myinit.c
-rwxrwxr-x  1 jarod jarod 877388 Jun  7 16:00 myinit_static*
```

-static link all dependency statically, so your binary can run on a machine without all these runtime installed

Answer (score 1):

From the gcc man page, it's used to enforce static linking of libraries. Some systems will always link statically if dynamic linking is not supported.

> -static
>              On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with the shared
>              libraries.  On other systems, this option has no effect.
>
> ```
>        This option will not work on Mac OS X unless all libraries (including libgcc.a)
>        have also been compiled with -static.  Since neither a static version of
>        libSystem.dylib nor crt0.o are provided, this option is not useful to most
>        people.
> ```