# Why does radare2 return an empty list of imports for a non empty main()?

Tags: c++, elf, radare2

I have the following little program I want to generate a call graph for:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  auto s = std::string("hello");
  s += " welt";
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it in a way which I hope preserves all information in order to be sure all required symbols can be found in the binary:

```
g++ foo.cpp -O0 -fno-function-cse -fomit-frame-pointer
```

Then I run `radare2` to generate a call graph, format it using Python's `pprint` and search for `sym.main`:

```
radare2 -qAc 'agCj' a.out \
    | python3 -c "import sys, json, pprint; pprint.pprint(json.load(sys.stdin))" \
    | grep -C 5 sym.main
```

The output contains:

```
{'imports': ['sym.std::allocator_char_::allocator',
              'sym.std::__cxx11::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::basic_string_charconst__std::allocator_char_const',
              'sym.std::allocator_char_::_allocator',
              'sym.std::__cxx11::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::operator___charconst',
              'sym.std::__cxx11::basic_string_char_std::char_traits_char__std::allocator_char__::_basic_string'],
  'name': 'sym.main',
  'size': 88}
```

Which means (at least I think so) that `main()` contains calls to the listed symbols.

When I now repeat everything but adding `-static` to the `g++` call, the `sym.main` entry does not contain any symbol any more:

```
g++ foo.cpp -O0 -g -static -fno-function-cse -fomit-frame-pointer
```

results in

```
{'imports': [], 'name': 'sym.main', 'size': 92},
```

Is there anything I can do about this? How can I see calls to the standard libraries as well when they are glued to the binary?

Comment: So, why the C language tag? The C language doesn't support `std::string`.

Comment: Try adding `-g`  flag to the g++ command.

Comment: @Thomas: because I'm generally interested how I can generate a call graph down to the standard library an this is not limited to C++ but (in my case) to C and C++

Comment: @Ripi2: this has no effect - actually I just forgot to add it to the line in my question

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095091/what-does-compilation-flag-static-really-means-for-gcc

Comment: Can you elaborate in which way this might help? I've added `-static` to link all dependencies and I see all references to functions called by `main()` disappear which is not what I expected. (I would expect references to symbols located in the statically linked standard libraries)